App Linking (AGC) Hauwei could not resolve
I have React Native project on Typescript and trying to add App Linking functionality.
I followed official instruction from here:

Signed in to AppGallery Connect, downloaded the agconnect-services.json file and added into root\android\app folder.

Configured the Maven Repository Address for the HMS Core SDK:



checked my gradle version (npm gradle -v), it's 10.8.3;

in build.gradle file in the root\android\ directory into buildscript > dependencies I added:


classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:10.8.3")
        classpath ("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.300")


in the folder root\android\ in the file settings.gradle I chaned like that:

pluginManagement { repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'Awesome'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK.
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
}


Added Build Dependencies: in the folder root\android\app in the file build.gradle I added:

apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'


Ran npm start, chose Andriod and got this error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:10.8.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/10.8.3/gradle-10.8.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/10.8.3/gradle-10.8.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.300.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.9.1.300/agcp-1.9.1.300.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.9.1.300/agcp-1.9.1.300.pom
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:10.8.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/10.8.3/gradle-10.8.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/10.8.3/gradle-10.8.3.pom
     Required by:
         project : > project :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin

What can be wrong and what I neeed to change?

The classpath should use existing versions ...
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.1")
classpath ("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.303")


Then I've got an error:
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (<path>\android\.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-2a3d3260-c15f-449c-a2c5-c1abd0172a3d)...

...to immutable location (<path>\android\.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) > Could not move temporary workspace (<path>\android\.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-2a3d3260-c15f-449c-a2c5-c1abd0172a3d) to immutable location (<path>\android\.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > BUILD FAILED in 2s.
